# Switch Registry Value from Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, registry

My requirement is that I need to change the value of a registry 
in particular this key `"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"` Value=`ProxyEnable`

The `REG_DWORD` (`0` or `1`) needs to be switched.
i.e
    SWITCH:
    IF proxy ENABLED then  DISABLE
IF proxy DISABLED then ENABLE

To Enable

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

To Disable

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

.

```
     @echo off
     setlocal
     set key="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
     set value=ProxyEnable
     set newdata=0
     for /f "tokens=2* skip=3" %%a in ('reg query %key% /v %value%') do (
     set type=%%a
     set data=%%b
   )
      echo %data% | find /i "%newdata%" > nul
     if %errorlevel% equ 0 (echo %newdata% already present
     ) else (
     echo reg add %key% /v %value% /t %type% /d %newdata% /f
     )
```

this is the code so far, unable to modify it.

Comment: Exactly what part are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 1):

To toggle/switch the value from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1, some simple maths helps simplify things: `set /a newdata=1-data`

Here's how I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set key="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set value=ProxyEnable
for /f "tokens=2* skip=2" %%a in ('reg query %key% /v %value%') do (
    set data=%%b
)
set /a newdata=1-data
reg add %key% /v %value% /d %newdata% /f
```

Comment: No need to trun around world to get the data value just set "tokens=3" and set "data=%%a".tokens in for mean  take column 3 only and skip mean skip 2 lines and delims by default is space between lines..

Comment: @hollopost you're right, however if someone uses this for/reg query line for a string, they'll want tokens=2* and %%b to get the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have to use `skip=2` :

```
@echo off
set key="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set "value=ProxyEnable"
for /f "tokens=2* skip=2" %%a in ('reg query %key% /v %value%') do call:Treat %%a %%b
exit/b

:Treat
echo %2 | find /i "1" && echo already present || reg add %key% /v %value% /t %1 /d 1 /f
```

If you want to disable it if present just replace the `echo already present` by :

```
reg add %key% /v %value% /t %1 /d 0 /f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set key="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set value="ProxyEnable"
set newdata=0x0
For /f "tokens=2,3 skip=2 delims= " %%a in ('reg query %key% /v %value%') do (
set type=%%a
set data=%%b
)
echo  %data% | find /i "%newdata%"  > nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (echo %data% already present & reg add %key% /v %value% /t %type% /d 1 /f
) else (
echo %data% already present & reg add %key% /v %value% /t %type% /d 0 /f
)
```